# Load sip from user installed /usr/local/lib in python3

Tags: apt, python3, pip, sip

I installed `python3-sip` using `apt` **and** `PyQt5-sip` using `pip3`.

The first one is in `/usr/share/sip/` and is version 4.19.7

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy python3-sip
python3-sip:
  Installed: 4.19.7+dfsg-1
  Candidate: 4.19.7+dfsg-1
  Version table:
 *** 4.19.7+dfsg-1 500
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The latter is in `/usr/local/` and its version is 4.19.15:

```
$ find /usr/local -iname "*sip*"
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/sip.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5_sip-4.19.15.dist-info
```

When I load `sipconfig` from python3, here's what I have:

```
>>> import sipconfig
>>> sipcfg = sipconfig.Configuration()
>>> print("sip_module_dir:%s" % sipcfg.sip_mod_dir)
sip_module_dir:/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages

>>> print("sip_version_str:%s" % sipcfg.sip_version_str)
sip_version_str:4.19.7
```

How to load `sip` from the one installed by `pip3`, i.e. the version 4.19.15 in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/` instead of the system wide `/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` installed with `apt`?

I always thought priority was given to user installed packages before system ones... but it's obviously not the case in this particular situation.

#### Updates:

I tried to install sip from its zip file here [1]:

So, I've unzipped the archive in /opt/sip-4.19.15 and then:

```
cd /opt/sip-4.19.15
$ python3 configure.py
```

which gives me:

```
This is SIP 4.19.15 for Python 3.6.7 on linux.
The SIP code generator will be installed in /usr/bin.
The sip.h header file will be installed in /usr/include/python3.6m.
The sip module will be installed in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.
The sip.pyi stub file will be installed in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.
The default directory to install .sip files in is /usr/share/sip.
Creating sipconfig.py...
Creating top level Makefile...
Creating sip code generator Makefile...
Creating sip module Makefile...
```

Then I run `make && sudo checkinstall` but `checkinstall` wants to overwrite files from the `sip-dev` package that come from Ubuntu repositories:

```
(Reading database ... 486665 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sip_4.19.15-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sip (4.19.15-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /opt/sip-4.19.15/sip_4.19.15-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/sip', which is also in package sip-dev 4.19.7+dfsg-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /opt/sip-4.19.15/sip_4.19.15-1_amd64.deb
/var/tmp/tmp.FjW48f0ufY/dpkginstall.log (END)
```

The really strange thing is that it seems it was actually overwritten as the version changed from 4.19.7 to 4.19.15 and last modification time is now:

```
/usr/bin/sip -V
4.19.15
```

I don't really understand the `checkinstall` behavior here...

Should I run the `configure.py` script with other output directories than the ones listed above? Like e.g.:

```
python3 configure.py \
-b /usr/local/bin \
-e /usr/local/include/python3.6 \
-d /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages \
--stubsdir /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages \
-v /usr/local/share/sip
```

#### More informations:

[1] https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip/installation.html#downloading
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip/command_line.html

Comment: The search order is whatever is in `sys.path` - you can check with `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` for example

Comment: I just saw that I have a python2.7 path (from ros-melodic) on top of all python3 paths. :/ And that the packages in /usr/lib are on top of the ones in /usr/local/lib. So...why numpy e.g. loads from /usr/local/lib and not sip?